# How can I impose a condition on Solve or FullSimplify?

Tags: vector

I would like to define a real 3-D vector as, say, `v = {x, y, z}`, but I want it to have a fixed norm and not necessarily a unit norm. I would like to impose this condition on the vector `v` before I start using `v` in a calculation. In particular, I want *Mathematica*  to insert `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = constant` during a calculation using `Solve` or `FullSimplify`. I have used `/. x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -> constant`, but this simply evaluates the result for the given constant. Is there way to impose my condition before/during the calculation.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` as a condition in `Solve` or `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the second argument of `Simplify`/`FullSimplify` to specify assumptions

```
v = {x, y, z};
Simplify[v.v, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == C[0]]
```

or use `Assuming[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == C[0], ...]`.